# Open access journals

Tags: soft-question, conferences, journals

With the advent of internet (and common sense) there is more and more demand for open-access research. Several researchers (including me) find it frustrating that published peer-reviewed research articles are behind paywalls. I am looking for journals and conferences (related to theoretical computer science, graph theory, combinatorics, combinatorial optimization) that make all accepted publications freely available to everyone.

Some such journals are [Theory of Computing](http://theoryofcomputing.org/), [The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/), [Logical Methods in Computer Science](https://lmcs.episciences.org/)

If you know more such journals (or) conferences, please mention them in your answers.

EDIT : As suggested by David Eppstein in his answer, I am adding one more constraint. Please write only those journals/conferences that do not charge authors exorbitant fees to publish.

Comment: It would be useful if each answer indicated whether the journals are on the SCI index. That's important for many people in Europe.

Answer (score 23):

Conferences with proceedings published in the [LIPIcs](http://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/) series:

- STACS
- FSTTCS
- CCC (since 2015)
- TQC (Theory of Quantum Computation, Communication and Cryptography)
- ICALP
- APPROX/RANDOM
- SoCG
- SWAT
- ESA
- MFCS

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you should also ask that the journal not charge authors exorbitant fees to publish?

The [Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications](http://jgaa.info/) and the [Journal of Computational Geometry](http://jocg.org/index.php/jocg) are free in both senses.

Answer (score 13):

[The Chicago Journal of Theoretical Computer Science](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/).

Answer (score 10):

- [Conference on Learning Theory (COLT)](http://www.ttic.edu/colt2012/)
- [Journal of Machine Learning Research (JMLR)](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/)

Comment: Can you provide some links?

Answer (score 8):

Papers on Graph Theory are also appearing on  [Ars Mathematica Contemporanea](http://amc.imfm.si/index.php/amc) , which is indexed by SCI.

The journal  [Discrete Mathematics & Theoretical Computer Science](https://dmtcs.episciences.org/)  is also open and indexed by SCI.

Answer (score 8):

The Directory of Open Access Journals has a [Computer Science](https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%22Electronic%20computers.%20Computer%20science%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%22journal%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A0%2C%22size%22%3A10%7D) category

Though it lists some of the journals already mentioned, I thought I'd share the link since it's an interesting resource.  Listings indicate whether there is a publication fee.

Comment: As an addendum to my previous answer, it might be worth checking out the list of [open access computer science journals available via SpringerOpen](https://www.springeropen.com/journals#Computer%20Science).

Answer (score 6):

[The Journal of Integer Sequences](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/).

Answer (score 5):

[Electronic Proceedings in Theoretical Computer Science](http://eptcs.org) is an open access series publishing workshop and conference proceedings. No charges for authors and proceedings editors.

Answer (score 5):

[Journal of Universal Computer Science](http://www.jucs.org/), it is on the SCI index.

Answer (score 5):

[Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research](http://www.jair.org) publishes work that (at least from 10000 feet) includes theoretical computer science, graph theory, and combinatorial optimization.

Comment: Note that JAIR requires authors to sign an exclusive copyright transfer form http://www.jair.org/copyright.pdf and that their license for online articles includes some strange restrictions http://www.jair.org/license.html that makes it incompatible with truly open licenses like CC-BY.

Comment: @a3nm That's a good thing as far as I'm concerned.  I'm all for remix art, but remix science is not something we need in these times.

Comment: Note that the license in question also disallows redistribution of verbatim copies in some cases, e.g., "Notwithstanding the foregoing, the Licessee may not publish, distribute, or sell complete volumes of JAIR in print, book, or journal form." As for remixing, there are lots of valid reasons to make derivative works of scientific articles, so I don't think it's a good idea to restrict them just because some derivative works would be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

The [International Conference on Database Theory](http://icdt.tu-dortmund.de/) (ICDT) publishes its proceedings in the [LIPIcs](http://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/) series. It is essentially the European-based database theory conference, with PODS (not open-access) being the American-based one.

There is a more detailed list of open-access venues in data management research and other neighboring areas on [this page](http://pierre.senellart.com/travaux/open-access/). (Disclaimer: I was involved in setting up the page.)

Answer (score 2):

The *[Discrete Analysis Journal](http://discreteanalysisjournal.com/)*, which works as a peer-reviewed overlay for arXiv, includes among [its topics](http://discreteanalysisjournal.com/about) "theoretical computer science" (and, for instance, [computational complexity](http://discreteanalysisjournal.com/section/2-computational-complexity).

From [their website](http://discreteanalysisjournal.com/for-authors):

> Discrete Analysis is an arXiv overlay journal. This means that while we have a conventional editorial board and refereeing process, we do not host the articles we accept or offer a formatting and copy-editing service. Instead, we simply link to preprints that are posted on the arXiv, which we believe amply meets the needs of our readers. As a result, the cost of running the journal, while not quite zero, is extremely low. Therefore, there are no charges for authors (and obviously none for readers, since the accepted papers are on the arXiv).

One issue appears to be that it does not mint DOIs (?).

Answer (score 1):

To stir the pot a bit, I will add [Algorithms](http://www.mdpi.com/journal/algorithms).  Publication fees are ~$300.  Some of the papers seem to have ridiculously short turnaround times, but there are some people on the Editorial Board that I know and some people that I respect.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't seem to be widely advertised, <strike>and it's not clear to me whether or not SIAM policy makes these open access forever [can someone clarify?]</strike>, many of the SIAM conferences currently have freely available official proceedings:

- [SODA](http://epubs.siam.org/action/showPublications?catType=proceedings&category=10.1555/category.40105908&expand=10.1555/category.40105908)
- [ALENEX](http://epubs.siam.org/action/showPublications?catType=proceedings&category=10.1555/category.40105910&expand=10.1555/category.40105910)
- [ANALCO](http://epubs.siam.org/action/showPublications?catType=proceedings&category=10.1555/category.40105911&expand=10.1555/category.40105911)

UPDATE: a3nm contacted SIAM directly about the SODA proceedings, and they said they did not guarantee open access in perpetuity :(. But least they are OA for now!

Comment: I have emailed SIAM about the SODA proceedings, asking whether they would be officially available in OA or not. The answer was "We cannot guarantee that the proceedings will open access in perpetuity." In addition, authors still have to sign an exclusive copyright transfer form. For these two reasons, I wouldn't count these conferences as open access.

Comment: @a3nm: Thanks for checking. Bummer! I agree with your assessment, but at least they are OA for now...

Comment: Yes they are, but from their answer, I'm not sure that they are even doing it on purpose. :) I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score -6):

Springer's *International Journal of Parallel Programming* offers authors the option to publish openly. They offer [online first](http://www.springerlink.com/content/0885-7458/preprint/) and [open access](http://www.springerlink.com/content/0885-7458/open/) articles, both with feeds available.

(I guess they have other journals with the same, but I have not checked.)

Comment: "Online first" does *not* mean open access; those articles are still behind the paywall (unless they happen to be open access articles).

Comment: And yes, all Springer journals offer the option to publish openly. However, it means that you will have to pay **[2000 EUR](http://www.springer.com/open+access/open+choice?SGWID=0-40359-12-683307-0)** (or 3000 USD) for each article!

Comment: Did not know that, sorry. In that case, this is certainly not a valid answer to the question. I will leave it on as a bad example and a reminder that Springer is, indeed, "evil".

Comment: 2000 EUR? I'm speechless.

Comment: Outside of academia, publishers who charge their authors for the privilege of being published are known as [vanity presses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_press).

Comment: Inside of academia, publishers who charge their authors for the privilege of being published are _also_ known as vanity presses.

Comment: @JɛﬀE I'm sure PLOS will be surprised to hear that. *Nearly all* open access journals have authorship fees. For example: "For PLoS Computational Biology the publication fee is US$2250." http://www.ploscompbiol.org/static/guidelines.action#publicationcharges

Comment: "Nearly all open access journals" should read "Nearly all open access journals in my field"...

Comment: @Jeffε: Just to clarify, I thought "vanity press" meant *anyone willing to pay* could get published. Though I find large pub fees abhorrent, I don't believe PLoS, Springer, etc. qualify as vanity presses under that definition. Rather, you go through peer review, and if you get accepted, then you may have to pay a publication fee (depending on publisher, journal, etc.). In TCS, my understanding is that many journals only have a fee for open access. From friends in biology I learned that many of their journals have fees just to publish, regardless of whether you want open access or not.